# SOLR proximity search boost for different slops

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to configure proximity search on my Solr. My requirement is want to enable two boost factors based on proximity for e.g. any document where the searched term are in the proximity of say 100 words should be more boosted than those documents where searched terms are in the proximity of 50 words.

Also how should I configure solr so that "stack over flow" and "flow stack over" yields same number of results.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't any term within 50 words also be within 100 words? And why should terms further apart be boosted more than those closer to each other? For you second question; that's the default behavior, so if you're not seeing that, you're asking for it specifically (such as for a phrase query).

Comment: Okay I got your point that 50 should be more boosted then 100 but regarding your point that 50 words also be with in 100 words, consider a scenario where in a document words are with in the range of 50 but in other documents are in range of 100, I want the the document where words are closer, should appear first in search results. How can I boost it?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it reasonable to assume that SOLR already boosts more relevant queries based on proximity implicitly and that you don't actually need explicit use of proximity operator?